# Validating regex on vue.js input field keypress event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The regex is validating the linux filepath perfectly. But the `keypress` event doesn't allow the user to type the first valid letter itself. When I start typing first letter as `/`, e.target.value is getting printed as empty space in console log.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<input
 type="text"
 class="inputChange validate"
 :id="item.name"
 :disable="false"
 v-model="item['name']"
 @keypress="validateLinuxPath"
/>
```

```js
validateLinuxPath(e) {
      let pattern = /^\/$|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+$/;
      let res = pattern.test(e.target.value);
      if (!res) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    },
```

Comment: FYI, keypress is no longer recommended - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Comment: your problem is that the keypress event is fired BEFORE the character is added to the value of the input ... `let res = pattern.test(e.key + e.target.value);` that way you can return `false` and the value of the input won't change

Answer (score 0):

You can change pattern.test(e.target.value) to e.key.match(pattern)

```
validateLinuxPath() {
  let pattern = /^\/$|(\/[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)+$/;
  let res = event.key.match(pattern);
  if (!res) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```